# getting error org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am getting this error in `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please add your POM.xml file or lib files screen shot you use in your application

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency or download the jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>{YOUR-VERSION}</version>
</dependency>
```

Based on the comments, add the following dependency also

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: now i am getting following error                                                                         SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question**

1. You are missing **spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar** or whatever spring-web-XXXX version you use in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem few days ago with m2eclipse (without WTP integration add on available via m2eclipse-extras) on Eclipse Indigo. I created a Maven Web Module and manually added the Dynamic Web Module facet to it. When I deployed it on Eclipse WST Tomcat Server, it appeared that my Maven dependencies are not getting pushed to the server when the project is published to it.

The solution was simple. Right Click on your web project in Project Explorer -> select 'Properties'. Under project properties, select 'Deployment Assembly'.

The Deployment Assembly property page shows the content that will be published as a assembled artifact by Eclipse to the server. You need to tell Eclipse that you want all your Maven dependencies to be published too.

Complete Answer here. [Tomcat & Spring Web - Class Not Found Exception org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322711/tomcat-spring-web-class-not-found-exception-org-springframework-web-context)